# Scrapy is trying to find a module that doesn't exist

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy

I'm trying to scrap a website and it comes up with this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File
"C:\Users\_________\Anaconda3\Scripts\scrapy-script.py", line 5, in
<module>
    sys.exit(scrapy.cmdline.execute())   File "C:\Users\_________\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy\cmdline.py",
line 109, in execute
    settings = get_project_settings()   File "C:\Users\_________\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy\utils\project.py",
line 68, in get_project_settings
    settings.setmodule(settings_module_path, priority='project')   File
"C:\Users\_________\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy\settings\__init__.py",
line 292, in setmodule
    module = import_module(module)   File "C:\Users\_________\Anaconda3\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in
import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 978, in _gcd_import   File
"<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load   File
"<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 936, in _find_and_load_unlocked 
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 205, in
_call_with_frames_removed   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 978, in _gcd_import   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961,
in _find_and_load   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 948, in
_find_and_load_unlocked ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'quotes_js'
```

the file shown at the bottom of the error doesn't exist on my computer can anyone help?

Comment: Please take your time to read this [stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Also what have you tried so far? Where is the relevant source code?

Comment: do you have a `scrapy.cfg` file in your directory where you run `scrapy-script.py` ? (or in a parent folder). If yes, does it contain "quote_js" as settings module?